# printing FFT at multiple points in tabulated form (matrix form)

Tags: matlab, matrix, export, fft, transpose

I've simulated the voltage at multiple points in time domain using C++. The output is printed out in tabulated form (i.e. time in first column and voltage at each point in the following columns).
I'm new to Matlab, but using it to fft the previous file in which i need to get a table of frequency in first column followed by frequency domain values for each point (in the same file).
I've tried all means to produce such table but it's always displayed in one column matrix (i.e. all data are set in one column matrix).

I need it to be in the form:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║     *f     V1(f)     V2(f)    .....    Vn(f)* ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║                                               ║
║     f1      ..        ..               ..     ║
║                                               ║
║     f2      ..        ..               ..     ║
║                                               ║
║     f3      ..        ..               ..     ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Also, if i'm able to create such matrix how can i get its transpose (to fft it once more w.r.t to space) ?

**The code is as follows:**

```
itr=importdata('filename.itr');

L=length(itr);             

T=itr(L,1);                

dt=itr(2,1);   

t=(0:dt:T-dt);

fs=1/dt;

FR_length=L;

[M,N]=size(itr(1:end,1:end));

f=-FR_length/2:FR_length/2-1;

f=f3.*(fs/FR_length);

for n=2:N

   FR=fft(itr(:,n),FR_length);   

end
```

can anyone help me with this?
Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed some of your code based on what I assume is the structure of input `itr`:

```
[L,N]=size(itr);                  
dt=itr(2,1);       
fs=1/dt;        
f=-L/2:L/2-1;    
f=f*(fs/L);    
FR =fftshift(fft(itr(:,2:end)));   
disp([f' FR])
```

The last line will display your data as a table on the command window.
Note that I removed the loop since matlab allows vectorized notation. Also added `fftshift` to get your frequencies and amplitudes to line up correctly. 
You can use `save` or `fprintf` to write to file, for instance as follows (you'll need to change the format string to match the number of data columns):

```
fid=fopen('test.dat','w')
fprintf(fid,'%f %f %f \n',[f ; real(FR)' ; imag(FR)'])
fclose(fid)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your fast and helpful reply. I tried both the "disp" command and the "fopen, fprintf, fclose" procedure but still getting the error "CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent". Any suggestions?

Comment: @user2804069 I would check the size of the arrays you are concatenating (f and FR). For starters also check the size of itr (see first line above), L should be number of time steps, N the number of series + 1.If L,N are not correct, transpose itr with `.'`

Comment: Note also that I made a small change above, removed preallocation which was not required.